# SAP SuccessFactors oData API. How to filter Effective Date?

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop, sap-successfactors

I build a Power BI Dashboard with a Dataset from SuccessFactors.

Here is the Link, that I used for querying `EmpJob` Object --->  https://api**preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/EmpJob

BUT! It returns only `EmpJob` Record effective as today.

I need the Records from 2010 till today, here is my Link -->
https://api**preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/EmpJob&fromDate=2010-01-01

But it fails :(

[image: Error]

Where is mistake? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is just not formatted correctly. You have an **&** instead of a **?**

https://api**preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/EmpJob?fromDate=2010-01-01